# Is there a way to hyperlink within an answer?

Tags: discussion

I've used superscripts as footnote references a few times (e.g.,  [...close-vim-from-the-command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24406/how-to-close-vim-from-the-command-line/24414#24414) ) .

Is it possible to link these so that they jump down to the appropriate place (such as the bottom/foot of the answer) when clicked on?

This is probably overkill, as answers are not usually so long that they aren't visually scan-able.  But this is the only case so far in which I've missed wikipedia's markup features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do footnoting or anchoring within a post at the moment.

We have a post size limit of 30,000 chars which is a lot, but not so much that IMHO you'd really need such things. And most posts, even larger posts, are nowhere near 30k chars.

Comment: Thanks.  30k?  Is there a badge for that?

Comment: I poured significant "elbow-grease" into a feature-request at https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18921/340383 to justify the need for it.